# HTML header row intermittently disappears when table sorted

Tags: javascript, html, python-3.x, char

The table header sporadically disappears upon filtering, the table header row needs to stay in place regardless if the character(s) used for filtering are in the table rows or not.

Example 1: Upon filtering for character 'x' (not in any td) the table rows disappear *AND* header row remains; this is good. Upon filtering on character 'z', (not in any td) the table rows **and** table header DISAPPEARS, this is bad.

Example 2: filtering for 'patio' (a) filter for 'pa'and header row disappears with only result rows showing, this is bad; (b) filter with 'atio' and both the table header row and the table row result lines are displayed, which is desired behavior.

'myFunction' is the filter

I've tested MS Edge, Chrome, Safari and Firefox. The html is generated from a Python script. I've spent +5 hours troubleshooting.

```
<html><head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=windows-1252">
                      <style>
                  td {
                      width: 200px;
                      height: 60px;
                  }
                  th {
                  cursor: pointer;
                  }
                  .selected {
                    background-color: green;
                  }
                  .bad {
                   background-color: red;
                  }
                      </style>
                      </head>
                  <body>
                  <h2>Search Box Below</h2>
                  <input id="myInput" onkeyup="myFunction()" placeholder="Search..." title="Type in a name" type="text">
                      <p style="font-size:30px">
Total tests: 10. Failed tests: 5. Skipped tests: 0.<br>
</p><p style="font-size:30px">
Report test time 0:00:00<br>
</p><table border="1" id="myTable">
<thead>

                              <tr style="">


<th>Facility</th>
<th>Test_group</th>
<th>Test_number</th>
<th>Description</th>
<th>Result</th>
<th>Execution_time</th>
<th>Information</th>
<th>Output</th>
                                </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>



                       <tr class="bad" style=""><td>Shower</td><td>972</td><td>9</td><td>Horse</td><td>Fail</td><td>0:09:51</td><td>Maroon</td><td></td></tr><tr class="selected" style=""><td>Patio</td><td>323</td><td>8</td><td>Dog</td><td>Success</td><td>0:16:35</td><td>Maroon</td><td></td></tr><tr class="selected" style=""><td>Shower</td><td>88</td><td>7</td><td>Pig</td><td>Success</td><td>0:08:54</td><td>Red</td><td></td></tr><tr class="bad" style=""><td>Patio</td><td>226</td><td>6</td><td>Pig</td><td>Fail</td><td>0:05:38</td><td>Maroon</td><td></td></tr><tr class="bad" style=""><td>Kitchen</td><td>982</td><td>5</td><td>Cat</td><td>Fail</td><td>0:09:01</td><td>Blue</td><td></td></tr><tr class="selected" style=""><td>Patio</td><td>654</td><td>4</td><td>Dog</td><td>Success</td><td>0:01:57</td><td>Red</td><td></td></tr><tr class="bad" style=""><td>Patio</td><td>96</td><td>3</td><td>Mule</td><td>Fail</td><td>0:16:29</td><td>Purple</td><td></td></tr><tr class="selected" style=""><td>Den</td><td>844</td><td>2</td><td>Horse</td><td>Success</td><td>0:12:11</td><td>Red</td><td></td></tr><tr class="bad" style=""><td>Room</td><td>323</td><td>1</td><td>Horse</td><td>Fail</td><td>0:02:30</td><td>Purple</td><td></td></tr><tr class="selected" style=""><td>Den</td><td>830</td><td>0</td><td>Horse</td><td>Success</td><td>0:06:42</td><td>Brown</td><td></td></tr>
</tbody>
</table>



<script>
const getCellValue = (tr, idx) => tr.children[idx].innerText || tr.children[idx].textContent;

const comparer = (idx, asc) => (a, b) => ((v1, v2) =>
    v1 !== '' && v2 !== '' && !isNaN(v1) && !isNaN(v2) ? v1 - v2 : v1.toString().localeCompare(v2)
    )(getCellValue(asc ? a : b, idx), getCellValue(asc ? b : a, idx));

document.querySelectorAll('th').forEach(th => th.addEventListener('click', (() => {
    const table = th.closest('table');
    Array.from(table.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(n+2)'))
        .sort(comparer(Array.from(th.parentNode.children).indexOf(th), this.asc = !this.asc))
        .forEach(tr => table.appendChild(tr) );
})));

function myFunction() {
  const input = document.getElementById("myInput");
  const inputStr = input.value.toUpperCase();
  document.querySelectorAll('#myTable tr:not(.header)').forEach((tr) => {
    const anyMatch = [...tr.children]
      .some(td => td.textContent.toUpperCase().includes(inputStr));
    if (anyMatch) tr.style.removeProperty('display');
    else tr.style.display = 'none';
  });
}

function resultFormatting() {
  var rows = document.getElementById("myTable").getElementsByTagName('tr');
  for (var i = 0; i < rows[0].children.length && rows[0].children[i].innerHTML !== "Result"; i++);
  for (var j = 1; j < rows.length; j++) {
    rows[j].classList.add(rows[j].children[i].innerHTML === "Success" ? 'selected' : 'bad');
  }
};
resultFormatting();
</script>

</body></html>
```

Comment: See creating a [mcve]. We need some type of debug to code, otherwise we're just blindly guessing.

Comment: Ok will add shortly, sorry, I understand.

Comment: @fjm *Ok will add shortly* - do that. I am seeing you question getting 'close' votes.

Comment: I'd put the header row in a `thead` and only operate on the data in `tbody`.

Comment: @TobiasK thank you, made changes, but filter behavior stays the same, using the same examples I noted.

Comment: You should consider fixing the HTML first. The table headers should be in a `<thead>` element, not a `<tbody>` and, the bulk of the table should exist inside `<tbody>` tags. As it stands, you've got an illegally structured table. You're lucky the browser is fixing it as much as it does!

Comment: Furthermore, if you structured your table better, you could target the `<tr>` elements that existed in the body, while ignoring those that contain column names. In doing so, you'd never be able to set 'display: none' to the `<tr>` that has the headings. Simples.

Comment: @enhzflep changes made, reviewed MDN doc on <tr> elements, but testing still has problem; new noted activity: I modify html then upon 'click to sort' or 'filter' the row after the header row has tbody tags around it so I end up with 2 tbody tags, do you have thoughts on why?

Answer (score 0):

Determined that 3 disparate js functions were creating conflict, incorporated python code to color code rows then replaced the filter function with non-conflict code and solved issue, marking closed.